# How do I set a default value for an attribute of type Object?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How do I set a default value for an attribute with type Object? In the example below, the default value for the country attribute should be an object with two properties: name and capital. At runtime, however, it defaults to the string "{'name':'France','capital':'Paris'}" and not an object.

```
<aura:attribute name="country" type="Object" default="{'name':'France','capital':'Paris'}" />
```

My work-around for now is to set the value in the init handler, but I'd still like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well using `type="Map"` works fine, and it returns object as expected.

`<aura:attribute name="country" type="Map" default="{'name':'France','capital':'Paris'}" />`

Here's the [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_collection.htm) to the section in the doc where attributes of collection type is discussed.

Comment: Yep, changing the type to Map works. I don't understand having a separate type of Map since in JavaScript an object is a map. At the very least the default syntax for map should also work for object.

Comment: This topic got bumped a year later... I think it merits mention, though, that the type names in Lightning are based on Apex conventions not JavaScript. In Apex, `Object` means the most general class from which all other objects inherit. So when you set `type="Object"` you're not being specific enough, and it may interpret as a string. When you set `type="Map"` it explicitly knows to look for key-value pairs.

Comment: Here's the supporting documentation where Salesforce recommends using the Map type instead of object: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_object.htm

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer is the correct one but as an alternative approach, you can set the object in a helper function which can be initialized by an init method when the component is created. For example:

```
cmp.set('v.country', {
  name: 'France',
  capital: 'Paris,
});
```

I like this approach because if there are many objects on the HTML, lot of code can be moved and HTML is cleaner.